# rxjs forkjoin doesn't exectue

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two rxjs Observables based on asynchronous FileReader operations. The subscriptions on each of them complete individually, but my attempt to `forkJoin` them never executes its `.subscribe` method. Clearly I've set it up wrong; heres the code:

```
let observe1 = this.Service1.parsedResponse$;
let observe2 = this.Service2.parsedResponse$;

observe1.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('subscription 1', data); // this executes
});

observe2.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('subscription 2', data); // this executes
});

let observeJoined = Observable.forkJoin(observe1, observe2);

observeJoined.subscribe((data: Object[]) => {
  console.log('are we forkjoined?', data); // never happens
});
```

What I'm ideally seeking is just two objects (data1, data2); they don't need to be combined into one result. I just need to know I have both of them before proceeding. Thanks!

Comment: `Observable.forkJoin(observe1, observe2)` are you pulling in `Observable` or do you need `Rx.Observable` ? Since what you have "should" work.

Comment: Seeing the same behavior, did you get this fixed somehow?

Comment: Got it. Was using the example from the ngDocs, where the observable isn't ever completed. ForkJoin only executes on completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
 this.Service1.parsedResponse$,
 this.Service2.parsedResponse$
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```